# InfoWindow marker personalizado con datos en Android

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android que tiene un mapa en el cual al dar clic en un marker muestra el infowindow de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que el infowindow apaezca de la siguiente manera y no lo se hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacerlo? Algún ejemplo? Gracias

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows?hl=es)

Para realizar esto debes crear un layout con lo que deseas aparezca en tu infoWindow, como ejemplo `infowindow_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_window_imagen"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/imagen_default" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_window_nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Carlo Estrada Solano" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_window_placas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_window_nombre"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Placas: SX5487" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_window_estado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_window_placas"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Estado: Activo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tendrías algo similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creas una clase que extienda de [`InfoWindowAdapter`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) la cual cargara el layout anterior:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater){
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
        //Carga layout personalizado.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        String[] info = m.getTitle().split("&");
        String url = m.getSnippet();
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText("Lina Cortés");
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas)).setText("Placas: SRX32");
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText("Estado: Activo");      
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker m) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Finalmente para cargar el infoWindow personalizado, a tu instancia GoogleMap mediante el método [`setInfoWindowAdapter()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) le asignas el  [`InfoWindowAdapter`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) personalizado.

```
myGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())));
```

Con esto obtendrás lo que deseas que es mostrar un infoWindow personalizado al dar clic en el marcador del mapa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! Ya hasta se me quitó las ganas de responder :P

Comment: @x4mp73r al contrario creo que es bueno varias respuestas porque el OP u otros, pueden encontrar detalles interesantes para lograr su objetivo, creo que toda la información es buena!, saludos!

Comment: Se que la pregunta es algo vieja, pero tengo una consulta. Como podria asignarle valores al InfoWindow desde un Intent que reciba el Adapter?