# ¿cómo agregar un marker personalizado en GoogleMaps en mi aplicacion Android?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, google-maps

soy nuevo en android...
Estoy ocupando la API de GoogleMaps en una aplicación y no tengo idea como hacer que el usuario agregue un MarkerOptions en el mapa (también agregar información al marker como en la imagen), y que este Marker se guarde en la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto se pregunto anteriormente... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25229/infowindow-marker-personalizado-android-studio/25247#25247

Comment: aquí hay otra relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35327/infowindow-android-studio

Comment: aca la documentacion que te puede orientar https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows?hl=es-419